# Child elements in webcomponent

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

Suppose we have a custom element to use in this way:

```
<list-image>
    <img src="" /> 
     ...
</list-image>
```

Where `list-image` displays `img` tags in a slider layout.

If the user of component inserts an `img` tag with:

```
document.querySelector('list-image').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="..." />');
```

...Is it possible for the component to know the new element `img`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the `<list-image>` custom element itself.

In the `connectedCallback()` method, observe mutations on child elements:

```js
customElements.define('list-image', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        //Detect <img> insertion
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length)
          console.info('Node added: ', mutation.addedNodes[0])
      })
    })

    observer.observe(this, { childList: true })
  }
})

function add() {
  document.querySelector('list-image')
          .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img alt="TOTO" />')
}
```

```html
<list-image>
  <img alt="Image1">
  <img alt="Image2">
</list-image>
<button onclick="add()">Add image</button>
```

Comment: Ok thank you much, this the only solution right? (i.e. there's no a specific callback for webcomponent)

Comment: Yes for custom elemen. But if you use Shadow DOM you could react on the `slotchange` event: https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#events-to-react-the-change-of-distributions

Comment: hayato.io link is dead

Comment: @Stefan see here: https://hayatoito.github.io/2016/shadowdomv1/

Answer (score 4):

Upadate, from this page: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/examples/howto-tabs

> New children will get slotted automatically and cause slotchange to
>   fire, so not MutationObserver is needed.

Comment: Could you please add a min example without MutationObserver?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't a my example but maybe you can see something here:

https://dev.to/coryrylan/understanding-slot-updates-with-web-components-oah